# Jade: HTML-escape content (not buffered code)

Tags: html, pug

This jade:

```
h1 a < b
```

Produces this HTML:

```
<h1>a < b</h1>
```

How can I get it to automatically escape the `<`? (i.e. not typing in `&lt;` myself)

```
<h1>a &lt; b</h1>
```

Comment: Why not use buffered code in this case?

Comment: To me, writing buffered code for general cases like this defeats the purpose of using a templating language. I want to write content without having extraneous characters like " and +.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this `h1 a < b` is a shortcut for `h1!= "a < b"`

just use this here:

```
h1= "a < b"
```